# With PHP IMAP connection to exchange server, what flag does exchange server use for UNSEEN emails?

Tags: php, imap, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

I am using the PHP IMAP library wrapped in the handy little class from Barbushin: https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap

I started testing against my gmail account, which would fetch my unread emails with the following.

```
$imap = new IMAP();
$unseen = $imap->searchMailbox('UNSEEN');
```

The function in the class does the following:

```
/*
 *      ALL - return all mails matching the rest of the criteria
 *      ANSWERED - match mails with the \\ANSWERED flag set
 *      BCC "string" - match mails with "string" in the Bcc: field
 *      BEFORE "date" - match mails with Date: before "date"
 *      BODY "string" - match mails with "string" in the body of the mail
 *      CC "string" - match mails with "string" in the Cc: field
 *      DELETED - match deleted mails
 *      FLAGGED - match mails with the \\FLAGGED (sometimes referred to as Important or Urgent) flag set
 *      FROM "string" - match mails with "string" in the From: field
 *      KEYWORD "string" - match mails with "string" as a keyword
 *      NEW - match new mails
 *      OLD - match old mails
 *      ON "date" - match mails with Date: matching "date"
 *      RECENT - match mails with the \\RECENT flag set
 *      SEEN - match mails that have been read (the \\SEEN flag is set)
 *      SINCE "date" - match mails with Date: after "date"
 *      SUBJECT "string" - match mails with "string" in the Subject:
 *      TEXT "string" - match mails with text "string"
 *      TO "string" - match mails with "string" in the To:
 *      UNANSWERED - match mails that have not been answered
 *      UNDELETED - match mails that are not deleted
 *      UNFLAGGED - match mails that are not flagged
 *      UNKEYWORD "string" - match mails that do not have the keyword "string"
 *      UNSEEN - match mails which have not been read yet
 *
 * @return array Mails ids
 */
public function searchMailbox($criteria = 'ALL') {
    $mailsIds = imap_search($this->imapStream, $criteria, SE_UID, $this->serverEncoding);
    return $mailsIds ? $mailsIds : array();
}
```

Just a handy wrapper for `imap_search();` http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php

Connected successfully to my exchange server over IMAP, I can now do the following:

```
$imap = new IMAP();
$unseen = $imap->searchMailbox('ALL');
```

This will retrieve ALL emails fine, in the inbox on Exchange (as per my connection).

`UNSEEN` (as documented) worked as expected on Google Mail but not Exchange 2010. `ALL` works as expected on both. I wondered whether Exchange 2010 used a different flag? `NEW` and `UNREAD` also do not work. And the returned details I can get from these mailID's do not contain an array of flags to reverse engineer from.

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it doesn't work, it's a bug in Exchange. The `UNSEEN` search term corresponds to the lack of the `\Seen` keyword (a message flag), see [RFC 3501, p. 52](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#page-52).

Comment: Exactly what I thought. Not the first time Microsoft totally ignore the idea of standardisation. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any issue link for it or/and a workaround for `imap_status` php function?

Comment: Good luck finding a public bug tracker for Exchange. If you're working at Microsoft, ask your manager, I suppose. If you're a customer, talk to your sales representative. You can implement workarounds via explicit state tracking via `UID` sets (and don't forget about `UIDVALIDITY` rules).